# Getting Dependency is not satisfiable: libgcrypt11 in Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, software-installation

I'm trying to install the editor [brackets](http://brackets.io/) in Lubuntu 16.04. But I'm getting this error

```
Error dependency is not satisfiable libgcrypt11 (>= 1.4.5)
```

Not sure why this is happening. I did a

```
sudo apt-get install libgcrypt11
```

and getting the following error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libgcrypt11 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

Someone could help me with this error?

Comment: DId you try searching the GitHub repo for Brackets? I found this: https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/12811.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`libgcrypt11` package is not available for Xenial](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=libgcrypt11). Instead it has newer [`libgcrypt20`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libgcrypt&searchon=names).

You can follow these steps to install Brackets in Xenial.

1. Download and install `libgcrypt11` for trusty from here http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libgcrypt11
2. Install the brackets from the website (by downloading the deb and using `dpkg`). Check this question if you need help regarding this

   - [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line)

Note: I have Brackets installed in Xenial. The above steps is verified by a Bracket contributor [here](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/12514#issuecomment-227048556)